# Unable to access CSS File in Node JS

Tags: html, css, node.js

i am a beginner in node.js
i have 3 files

- cal.js
- cal.html
- style.css

neither my node.js is accessing css file nor html is accessing it .
earlier when i used internal css html file was perfect but node was not .
**help me in refrence to this below code**

```
const express= require("express");
 const bodyparser =require("body-parser");

 const app=express();
 app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))



   app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile( __dirname+"/cal.html");
    console.log(__dirname); 

     });
   app.post("/",function(req,res)
   {
     var n1=Number(req.body.num1);
     var n2=Number(req.body.num2);
    var n=n1+n2;

    res.write('<h1 class="result">sum is='+n+'</h1>'); 
    res.send();


      })
   app.listen(2000,function()
    {
    console.log("server is running");
     });
```

> html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
  <title>server </title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">


   </head>
   <body>
    <form action="/" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="num1" placeholder="number1">
    <input type="text" name="num2" placeholder="number2">
    <button type="submit" name="button">calculate</button>
    </form>

   <script src="cal.js"></script>

   </body>
   </html>
```

> css file

```
body{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;font-family: cursive;
    background-color: pink;


}
.result{
    color: green;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Can you tell, where CSS and JS files are located with respect to project root?

Comment: @KPranavRam i have a folder named **calculator** in side which i have 3 files cal.html    -style.css                                                                                                                               -cal.js

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`express.static`](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html) middleware in order to serve static files.

I see in you code that the HTML file is located in `__dirname`, so this line should work for you:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname));`

Answer (score 0):

try to add a dot in here

```
res.sendFile( __dirname+"./cal.html");
```

and in here

```
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style.css">
```

Comment: No it says the following error **no such file or directory**

Answer (score 0):

*This is the standard way of doing it:*
`CSS` and `JS` file should be placed in folder in the following structure:

```
project_root
|
----index.js(or)app.js {node.js file}
|
----shared
    |
    ----css
    |   |
    |   ----<CSS Files>
    ----js
        |
        ----<JS Files>
```

in your express app file, after  `app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended:true}))`, add
`app.use(express.static('shared'))`
Access necessary `CSS` and `JS` files from html by using `/css/<filename>` `/js/filename`
*[Example](https://repl.it/repls/VioletredVisibleRate)*

Comment: sorry !! what does this shared means??

Comment: @PallaviVohra shared is folder inside project root and css and jss are sub-folders of shared. It's just a convention.

Comment: No, it should be inside the project root directory

Comment: sorry i have sorted css file just like you said but its not working .. **calculator/shared/css/style.css** and  after this  **app.use(express.static('shared'));** exactly this i have written.. but its seems not

Comment: Please use the link to example in my post to see above example